# Generate Javascript file dynamically on iOS

Tags: javascript, ios

I am working with a `WKWebView` and I need to get some Javascript from a server and execute this javascript on my `WKWebView`.

Basically, to have this javascript, I make a call to an API that sends a JSON like :

```
{
    "script" : "function()..." // the content of the script is a string here
}
```

So my question : how can I inject this script ? I first need to create a JS file with this content, right ? Until now, I was injecting JS from files that were first added to my project.

I know I could create a file like that :

```
NSError *error;
NSString *stringToWrite = @"function()... my javascript";
NSString *filePath = [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) firstObject] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myScript.js"];
[stringToWrite writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
```

But then, the user would see this file on his / her iPhone, right ?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I now get the string from the server and execute the Javascript from that string like that :

evaluateJavaScript

```
myWKWebView.evaluateJavaScript(scriptString, completionHandler: { (result, error) in

     // ...

})
```